# Checking for even length with pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I saw this snippet and I don't understand how this is being done with pattern matching. It'd be great if someone can explain it to me (or anyone else who might not understand this as well)

```
def even_length?([]) do
  true
end

def even_length?([_head | tail]) do
  !even_length?(tail)
end
```

I'm simply lost when it comes given inputs such as `[1, 2]` or `[3, 4, 5]`

Thanks in advance.

Source of code: https://gist.github.com/mauricioabreu/8fdb64bef6a938dd1e34ac15e9268d4d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a very clever piece of code, though it might be easier to understand if you follow it's execution step by step.

Before we look at a few examples, it's important that you understand that Elixir implements [Lists as Linked Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192923/lists-vs-tuples-what-to-use-and-when) and each list has a `head` and a `tail` where the tail itself is a separate list term.
Every list (other than an empty list) can be written as `[ head | tail ]`:

```ex
[1] == [ 1 | [] ]
# => true

[3, 2, 1] == [ 3 | [2, 1] ]
# => true

[3, 2, 1] == [ 3 | [ 2 | [ 1 | [] ] ] ]
# => true
```

---

#### 1. Empty List `[]`

Calling `even_length?([])` would match the first signature and directly return `true`, since that's the [base case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) of our recursive function.

#### 2. With One Element `[x]`

When calling the function on a list with one element, the VM would skip the first function definition (since it's not empty), and move on to the second one which in turn calls the function recursively on just the tail part and inverting the boolean value. If we expand the call stack, it would look like this:

```ex
even_length?([1])          # `1` is head, `[]` is tail
# => !even_length?([])
# => !(true)               # We know value is `true` from base-case
# => false
```

#### 3. With Two Elements `[x, y]`

Same thing, but we will invert the result once more (since the function will be called an extra time):

```ex
even_length?([2, 1])          # `2` is head, `[1]` is tail
# => !even_length?([1])       # `1` is head, `[]` is tail
# => !(!even_length?([]))
# => !(!(true))               # We know value is `true` from base-case
# => !(false)
# => true
```

#### 4. With Three Elements `[x, y, z]`

```ex
even_length?([3, 2, 1])       # `3` is head, `[2, 1]` is tail
# => !even_length?([2, 1])    # `2` is head, `[1]` is tail
# => !(!even_length?([1]))    # `1` is head, `[]` is tail
# => !(!(!even_length?([])))
# => !(!(!(true)))            # We know value is `true` from base-case
# => !(!(false))
# => !(true)
# => false
```

#### 5. With N Elements `[ ... ]`

And this will continue repeating. The simplest way to understand what this function does is that it has defined that a List with 0 elements should return `true`, and for every extra element it should invert (boolean `not`) the previous value.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Thanks for taking time to write this up. I can't vote this up yet, but when I can, I'll do it one day. Thanks again! Really appreciate it. I think I can understand this now

Answer (score 0):

When you call `even_length?([1, 2])` it matches: `even_length?([_head | tail])` 
where `_head` is **1** and `tail` is **[2]**.

Then, recursively, it call: `!even_length?([2])` which matches `even_length?([_head | tail])` where `_head` is **2** and `tail` is **[]**.

Since `tail` is **[]** then, it call: `!even_length?([])` which matches the first function `even_length?([])` where returns **true**.

Comment: I think I can understand how it's matched between those two functions from your explanation, but I still don't understand how the true false travels to the point it returns the final result. Care to elaborate more on that?